# Why jars added to Deployment Assembly do not show up in Project Explorer (Eclipse Photon) under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

Working on a Dynamic Web Project I added a guava *jar* file to *Deployment Assembly* (Eclipse Photon) - thru Add -> Java Path Build Entry (same happens with Add -> Archives From File System)

[image]

I see that this jar gets deployed to the server and is actually inside `/WEB-INF/lib` of the generated and deployed WAR.

But my Project Explorer window looks like this and its `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder is empty (I did project refresh)!

**Is it normal behaviour?**

In my opinion it breaks Least Astonishment Principle a lot!

[image: jars]

Comment: Does it? You didn't copy the jar into your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't appear there unless you actually copy the jar into the workspace (or link it, possibly).